# How do I transform accented characters in an ODATA WCF DataService

Tags: .net, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services

I've got a stringly typed WCF custom data provider service set up which returns some simple user information.  How do I ensure that accented characters for example are correctly transformed to be valid in the XML feed ?

An example in the current output is `<d:LastName>Toqué</d:LastName>`

I've tried using EntityPropertyMappingAttribute with type Xhtml but that throws an exception as it does not work with custom types

Note that if I call the service and ask for JSON, the accents are transformed

Comment: Which component would throw the exception? Do you mean that with EntityPropertyMappingAttribute, the response payload is not a valid XML?

Comment: No, without EntityPropertyMappingAttribute the xml feed is generated but cannot be read by IE for example because the é is not escaped.  I thought the attribute might be the way to solve it but I can't get that to work at all